Por qué no se muestran los datos de los 3 usuarios creados en la grilla?
Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio 2022 con .NET, en C#. Necesito mostrar en una grilla datos de usuarios. Harcodee datos de 3 usuarios distintos, pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de mostrarlos en la grilla.
Al sacar la linea "this.dgvUsuarios.AutoGenerateColumns = false;" los datos aparecen en la grilla pero se repiten las columnas. (Adjunto imagen del problema)

namespace AcademiaABM
{
    public partial class Usuarios : Form
    {
        public Usuarios()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dgvUsuarios.AutoGenerateColumns = false;


        }

        public void Listar()
        {

            List<UsuarioModel> usuarios = new List<UsuarioModel>
            {
                new UsuarioModel { ID = 1, Nombre = "Juan", Apellido = "Perez", Usuario = "jperez", Email = "juan.perez@email.com", Habilitado = true },
                new UsuarioModel { ID = 2, Nombre = "Ana", Apellido = "Gomez", Usuario = "agomez", Email = "ana.gomez@email.com", Habilitado = false },
                new UsuarioModel { ID = 3, Nombre = "Carlos", Apellido = "Sanchez", Usuario = "csanchez", Email = "carlos.sanchez@email.com", Habilitado = true }
            };
            dgvUsuarios.DataSource = usuarios;
        }

        private void Usuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Listar();
        }

        private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Listar();
        }

        private void toolStripContainer1_ContentPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    // Clase Usuario separada para manejar los datos
    public class UsuarioModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Habilitado { get; set; }
    }
}


Y esa grilla, que parece ser winforms pero puede ser cualquier cosa, tiene las columnas bien generadas?
